# How to display all commands using jline3

Tags: jline, jline3

I have a `TreeCompleter` (Scala code) which works as expected:

```
val treeCompleter = new TreeCompleter(
    node("bindkey"),
    node("cls"),
    node(
      "custom",
      node("Option1", node("Param1", "Param2")),
      node("Option2"),
      node("Option3")
    ),
    node("help"),
    node("set"),
    node("sleep"),
    node("testkey"),
    node("tput")
)
```

However, if the user's first keypress is a tab I would like all of the top-level node values to be displayed, which should show them the available commands. How can this be done?

The github project that contains the above code is here: https://github.com/mslinn/jline-example/blob/master/src/main/scala/CliLoop.scala

I don't care if the answer is in Java or Scala, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to unset the `INSERT_TAB` option:

`reader.unsetOpt(LineReader.Option.INSERT_TAB)`

This will do the trick and `tab` will display completion instead of being inserted.

Comment: Works perfectly!